# Pass/Returning not working

Tags: java

```
public class BlackJack {

    static String[] deck = new String[52];

    //Creates Deck of cards
    public static void main (String[] args)  {      
        String[] suit = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
        String[] rank = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" };

        for (int a=0; a < rank.length; a++) {
            for (int b=0; b < suit.length; b++){
                deck[suit.length*a + b] = (rank[a] +" of "+ suit[b]);
            }
        }

        //Trying to get this to print out the returned card name
        String card = "G";
        randomCard(card);
        System.out.println(card);
    }

    //Pulls a random card from the deck
    public static String randomCard(String cardName) {          
        //Generates a random number between 0 and 52
        int card = (int)(Math.random()*53);
        cardName = (deck[card]);
        return cardName;

    }

}
```

So the first part of my main method generates a deck of cards and works completely fine (I've tested it separately). I'm trying to get my second method *randomCard* to return one randomly drawn card from the deck. I can only get it to print out 'G' which is there for me to test to see if its working or not. Help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the returned value.

```
card = randomCard(card);
```

The assignment made inside the method `cardName = deck[card];` only updates the methods local `String` reference `cardName` and has no effect outside of the method's scope.

Also for a better way to randomly distribute cards, look at [`Collections.shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List,%20java.util.Random)). Read [this blog entry](http://blog.codinghorror.com/shuffling/?r=31644) and [this one](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/) for more on shuffling.

```
ArrayList<String> deck = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] suit = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
String[] rank = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
        "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" };

for (int a=0; a < rank.length; a++) {
    for (int b=0; b < suit.length; b++){
        deck.add(rank[a] +" of "+ suit[b]);
    }
}

Collections.shuffle(deck, new SecureRandom());
String randomCard = deck.get(0);
```

Comment: Oh my... Thank you so much! I'm very new to this still

Answer (score 2):

Your `randomCard` has some errors.

```
public static String randomCard() { // no need for an argument
    int card = (int)(Math.random()*52); // was 53, but there are only 52 cards - 
                                        // you want to generate the number 
                                        // between 0 and 51
    String cardName = deck[card]; // removed (" ")
    return cardName;
}
```

Then call the method with :

```
card = randomCard();
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable.  Your method

```
public static String randomCard(String cardName)
```

does not (and cannot) change the String object being passed in.  This

```
cardName = ("deck[card]");
```

only changes the local `cardName` reference to point to a new string.  However, the object passed in does not change.  Therefore, you need to explicitly assign `card` to the return value of the method

```
card = randomCard(card);
```

Comment: i appreciate it! I had added the " " into the deck[card] just as a test to see if i could get it to return that and not the actual card. was part of my process of elimination and i just forgot to remove them before i copy/pasted here. Thank you very much though

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the reason for this: Pass by value of the string.
Adding to Weston's solution, when you assign

```
card = randomCard(card);
```

it actually assigns the returned value in the *card* variable, But when you do

```
cardName = (deck[card]);
```

all it does is change the value of the *cardName* parameter of the function randomCard.